# How to subdivide a row into three columns in tables

Tags: tables, formatting

See the following table:
[image]

Using the following code:

```
\begin{table}[H]
  \centering
  \caption{Caption }
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
  \begin{tabular}{|p{2cm}||c|c|c|}
    \hline
 {\textbf{Molecule}} & {\textbf{Ground State Energy (Hartree)}} \\
    \cline{2-4}
    & \textbf{Multiplicity 1 } & \textbf{Multiplicity 3} & \textbf{Multiplicity 5}\\
    \hline
    $ \mathrm{C_4H_8N_2}$ & -264.84232294  & -264.8423229345  & -264.8423248314  \\ 
  \end{tabular}
\label{tab:multiplicity}
\end{table}
```

I would like the ground state energy Hartree title to be centered so that it encompasses multiplicity 1,  multiplicity 3 and multiplicity 5.
In other words, in the first row, how do I remove the line which creates a 2nd and 3rd column and then center the ground state energy title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you just need to use the `\multicolumn` command like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]
  \centering
  \caption{Some caption}
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
  \begin{tabular}{|p{2cm}||c|c|c|}
    \hline
    {\textbf{Molecule}} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{Ground State Energy (Hartree)}} \\
    \cline{2-4}
                        & \textbf{Multiplicity 1 } & \textbf{Multiplicity 3} & \textbf{Multiplicity 5}\\
    \hline
    $ \mathrm{C_4H_8N_2}$ & -264.84232294  & -264.8423229345  & -264.8423248314\\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \label{tab:multiplicity}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: 1]

Comment: You should write `\multicolumn{3}{c|}` instead of `\multicolumn{3}{|c|}`. Indeed, if the user loads the package `array`, the width of one small rule will be too wide (because, with `array`) each rule is drawn with its own space and increase the total width or height of the tabular).

Comment: You are right, I will make the edit. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

The solution to your problem is indeed the `\multicolumn` command as
Niranjan posted in his answer.

However I suggest you some changes to better handle your table:

1. You can use `mhchem` (or other) package. This could help to write the molecules.
2. You can also use `siunitx` package for the S type column, which improves the number alignment (look at the following example).
3. The last is just an opinion, but it looks better a table with no vertical lines. I create mine with the help of `booktabs` package.

This is an example of the two tables for comparison. I added an additional line in each one to show the numbers alignment.

```
\documentclass        {article}
\usepackage           {booktabs} % \toprule, \midrule, \cmidrule, \bottomrule
\usepackage           {lipsum}   % dummy text
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}   % \ce, for writing chemistry (EDIT: ADDED version=4)
\usepackage           {siunitx}  % SI units, and S column type for better numbers alignment

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{table}[h]
  \centering
  \caption{Original}\label{tab:multiplicity1}
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
  \begin{tabular}{|p{2cm}||c|c|c|}
    \hline
    \textbf{Molecule} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{Ground State Energy (Hartree)}} \\
    \cline{2-4}
    & \textbf{Multiplicity 1} & \textbf{Multiplicity 3} & \textbf{Multiplicity 5}\\
    \hline
    $\mathrm{C_4H_8N_2}$ & -264.84232294 & -264.8423229345 & -264.8423248314 \\
    $\mathrm{C_4H_8N_2}$ & -264.84232    & -264.842322     & -264.842324831  \\ % just to show what happens
    \hline % I'm assuming the table is closed
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{table}[h]
  \centering
  \caption{Suggested\strut}\label{tab:multiplicity2}
  \begin{tabular}{p{2cm}S[table-format=-3.8]S[table-format=-3.10]S[table-format=-3.10]}
    \toprule
    \textbf{Molecule} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Ground State Energy (Hartree)}} \\
    \cmidrule{2-4}
                & {Multiplicity 1} & {Multiplicity 3} & {Multiplicity 5}\\
    \midrule
    \ce{C4H8N2} & -264.84232294    & -264.8423229345  & -264.8423248314 \\
    \ce{C4H8N2} & -264.84232       & -264.842322      &    0.84232483   \\ % just to show what happens
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:** I forgot to add `version=4` to `mhchem`. There was a warning, of course.

Answer (score 2):

With `tabularray` and `mhchem` package and `siunitx` tlbr library, formatting as "profesiona look":

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}         % new table
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}        % SI units, and S column type for better numbers alignment
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}  % \ce, for writing chemistry

\begin{document}
    \begin{tblr}{hline{1,Z}=1pt, hline{3}=0.6pt,hline{2}=solid,
                 colspec = {l 
                            S[table-format=-3.8]
                            S[table-format=-3.10]
                            S[table-format=-3.10]
                            },
                 row{1,2} = {font=\bfseries},
                 cell{1}{2} = {c=3}{c}, % multi-column, start in 1st row, 2nd column,
                                        % span 3 columns, align center
                 cell{1}{1} = {r=2}{l}, % multi-row, start in 1st row, 1st column,
                                        % span 2 rows, align center
                    }
Molecule        & {{{Ground State Energy (Hartree)}}}           &&                      \\
                & {{{Multiplicity 1}}}  & {{{Multiplicity 3}}}  & {{{Multiplicity 5}}}  \\
\ce{C_4H_8N_2}  & -264.84232294         & -264.8423229345       & -264.8423248314       \\
\ce{C_4H_8N_2}  &  -64.84232            &  -64.842322           &  -64.842324831        \\
\ce{C_4H_8N_2}  & -264.842329            & -264.84232293          & -264.8423248314     \\
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]